# How to check if a Marshmallow schema's Datetime field is less than today's date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have an endpoint that accepts `POST` method. The `POST` body contains a `DateTime` field of format - `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%MZ"`. I need to validate if that datetime is less than current Datetime in UTC. I'm using `Marshmallow` to validate the request body.

```
run_datetime = fields.DateTime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%MZ")
```

Are there any inbuilt validators for this case to validate `DateTime` field. Or should I be writing a custom function for this to compare the `run_datetime` with today's `UTC's datetime`.

Comment: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#field-validators-as-methods

Comment: Nope, no builtin. Define your own validator (see above link to docs).

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in validator that can solve your particular issue at hand, take a look at the available validators [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.validate.html).
Although, defining your own validator is trivially easy, for your particular case: `fields.Datetime` will accept an argument named `validate` which can take a function that returns a bool. For example, I quickly defined a lambda here to validate if the datetime is more recent than "now":

```py
from datetime import datetime
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

NOW = datetime(2020, 11, 23, 14, 23, 0, 579974)

class User(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    # Define an arbitrary datetime here like NOW or just use datetime.now()
    date_created = fields.DateTime(required=True, validate=lambda x: x > NOW)

# This will succeed
User().load(dict(
    id=10,
    name="Test",
    # Note that this date is more recent than previously defined NOW
    date_created="2020-11-23T14:24:40.224965",
))
#{'date_created': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 23, 14, 24, 40, 224965),
# 'id': 10,
# 'name': 'Test'}

# While this will fail
User().load(dict(
    id=10,
    name="Test",
    # Here the date is one month behind than NOW
    date_created="2020-10-23T14:24:40.224965",
))
# ValidationError: {'date_created': ['Invalid value.']}
```